# Entanglement, quadrics and $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}^3)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, quadrics

First of all: I apologise in advance for if my question will be arid, wrong written or even nonsensical.

I was at a talking with a professor last week, and the question of "Entanglement and Algebraic Geometry" came out.
What emerged really fascinated me, so I'm here to ask more clarifications, explanations or even references.

Here is what I "understood" and wrote down on a piece of paper (that is, heard and hence reporting here):

"Say we have two systems made of states. It's easy to understand what entanglement is from a geometric point of view. Those systems can the thought as objects in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}^3)$ (projective space). The states they are made of can be pure or not pure. We can see the pure states are basically quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}^3)$, while the non pure states are what are called the entangled ones".

So I'm asking you: can you explain me better the above statement, assuming it's not meaningless? Or provide me some reference, paper, books...

Thank you so much!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @Sasha I literally wrote "Can you explain me better the above statement, assuming it's not meaningless? Or provide me some reference, paper, books..."

Comment: I am no expert, and I also think this question is too vague for MO. However googling "entangled states and quadrics in projective space" threw back the following habilitation thesis: Frédéric Holweck. On the projective geometry of entanglement and contextuality. On page 2 of the introduction he explains that states in a 2-qubit system correspond to points $(a_{00},a_{01},a_{10},a_{11})\in \mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$; the unentangled ones lie on a quadric $Q=\{a_{00}a_{11}-a_{10}a_{01}=0\}$ and the entangled ones on the complement of the quadric $\mathbb{P}^3\setminus Q$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C}^3)$?

Comment: Piotr Achinger — I am wondering the same thing.

Comment: @DanielAsimov and Piotr Achinger Well honestly I was wondering the same thing. In my ignorance I did not dare to say it was wrong, for as I said I am no expert. Yet if you too wonder what that is, then I guess it was either a typo of my writing, or an error from the professor. 

Anyway, thank you all (thank you for the downvote too)

Comment: @TomDucat Thank you so much! I will read that!

Comment: If I had to guess, the confusion probably stems from the equivalent notations $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}^3) = \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$, i.e. that the projectivization of the 3-dimensional complex vector space is the 2-dimensional complex projective space.

Comment: It sounds like this is terminology for (quantum) finite state machines.  A textbook on quantum computing for mathematicians might be appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Let me just make a couple of comments on the question to clean up the confusion about the correct dimension of the projective space — it should be $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$. The state space of a qubit is the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$, and the $n$-qubit is obtained as tensor product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{C}^2$. There are different choices for symmetry group, one possible is SLOCC (stochastic local operations with classical communication) which for the $n$-qubit would be the group $\SL_2(\mathbb{C})^{\times n}$ acting on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$. For the 2 qubits, this would be $\SL_2(\mathbb{C})\times\SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$. The action can be identified with the group acting on $2\times 2$-matrices by left and right multiplication. The orbits of the group on the projective space associated to $\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2$ (that is the $\mathbb{P}^3$ that should appear in the question) correspond to the different states the system can be in.

Now algebraic geometry tells us that there are two orbits for the action of $\SL_2(\mathbb{C})\times\SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ acting on $\mathbb{P}^3$. One open orbit, isomorphic to $\PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and one closed orbit isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ — that is the quadric mentioned in  Tom Ducat's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450048/entanglement-quadrics-and-mathbbp2-mathbbc3#comment1163095_450048). The closed orbit can be obtained as the orbit of an elementary tensor, so it consists of pure states. The open orbit consists of the entangled states, it is the orbit of the so-called Bell state.

There is further literature on this, people have been working on using geometric invariant theory etc to understand polynomial invariants which separate different entangled states in $n$-qubits. My knowledge there is a bit dated, but it seemed that 4 qubits is the state of the art.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb C)$?  Isn't it just $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb C)$?  (I ask because, as algebraic groups, $\operatorname{PSL}_2 = \operatorname{SL}_2/Z(\operatorname{SL}_2)$ literally *is* $\operatorname{PGL}_2$, i.e., the obvious map to $\operatorname{PGL}_2$ is an isomorphism; whereas, for those fields $k$ for which $k^\times \ne (k^\times)^2$, $\operatorname{SL}_2(k)/Z(\operatorname{SL}_2(k))$ is not the group of $k$-rational points of an algebraic group in any natural way.)

Comment: I think it's standard to take $PSL_n$ to mean the adjoint form of $SL_n$. In algebraic group language I believe this would be $SL_n/\mu_n$.

Comment: @StevenSam that's the same as what LSpice wrote because $Z(SL_2)=\mu_2$ in your notation.